# Overriding maya rig in unity using blender

Tags: rigging, export, unity

I am trying to override an existing rig in a unity project that was made in Maya so I could use items that were made in blender and animations as well in the project.

The problem is that the animations would not work when I export as .fbx from Blender and override the file directly in unity, which has to do with the rig that was made in Maya,
the hierarchy of the .fbx changes and the armatures does not match.

**Background:**
The current rig that is in unity does not have scale and location applied correctly from when it was exported from Maya to unity.

Comment: Could you attach your .blend file here: https://blend-exchange.com/